# How to change the MIME type of CSS background-image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a website. I created a subdomain for delivering images. However, the images are blocked by the browser's CORB. This happens because the browser recognises those jpeg images as text/html. How can I change the content type of those images?

It should be noted that:
- I use Wordpress.org.
- The images are background-images of divs. They are called from here:

```css
.stamp2 {
  background: url(https://assets2.outre.ml/top-5-apps-768x552.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
```

- [This is a snip of browser's network log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/todOY.png)

> The browser does not load those resources as they are blocked by the browser's CORB which is a security system that blocks suspicious text/html, etc. resources.

- The images are not loaded. They give an error message in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <url> with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Comment: So, you're using image URLs coming from let's say `https://images.your-domain.net/wp-content/uploads/xxxx/xx/sample.jpg` as background-image - and Apache or whatever webserver is running there delivers this as `Content-Type: text/html`? Please give an example of such a `background-image: url(...);`.

Comment: I may not understand what you are asking for completely, but the example is straight in the post. The code `.stamp2 { ... ` is the same code I am using to get the images.